# How can I to make the CKEditor 5 balloon editor inline editor work?

Tags: 10, wysiwyg

Drupal 10 comes with CKEditor 5, which allows for inline editing, including a [balloon editor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/predefined-builds.html#inline-editor).

It doesn't seem there is a setting in Drupal 10 for that yet.
How can I activate the balloon editor?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible within Drupal core. Balloon editing is not just a config setting, this would be a separate code package from CKeditor.

Comment: Also to note - even though things are advertised on CKEditors website does not mean it was also implemented in full in Drupal, like Collaborative Editing. It can still be done, but you have to create the backend plugins to enable the functionality if it is not there.